# Circular progress bar which changes the stroke and values as the buttons get clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the percentage of the progress bars as the buttons are clicked.

I want to add multiple buttons to change the percentage.

I am new to javascript coding the bars are set to a particular value, how can I change it to different different values.
I want to change the percentage of the progress bars as the buttons are clicked.

I want to add multiple buttons to change the percentage.

I am new to javascript coding the bars are set to a particular value, how can I change it to different different values.

```html
<html><body>
    <style>
    * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 .container {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     background-color: #0d0d0d;
     width:700px;
     height:220;
}
 .container__progressbars {
         display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    min-width: 170px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
}
 .progressbar {
     position: relative;
     width: 170px;
     height: 270px;
     transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
 .progressbar__svg {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
 .progressbar__svg-circle {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     fill: none;
     stroke-width: 10;
     stroke-dasharray: 440;
     stroke-dashoffset: 440;
     stroke: #fff;
     stroke-linecap: round;
     transform: translate(3px, 3px);
}
 .shadow-npd {
     filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #f63);
}
 .shadow-business-con {
     filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #3bf);
}
 .shadow-capex {
     filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #f3f);
}
 .shadow-child-part-inv {
     filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #ff3);
}
 .circle-npd {
     animation: anim_circle-npd 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}
 .circle-business-con {
     animation: anim_circle-business-con 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}
 .circle-capex {
     animation: anim_circle-capex 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}
 .circle-child-part-inv {
     animation: anim_circle-child-part-inv 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}
 .progressbar__text {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
     color: #fff;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     border-radius: 0.25em;
     transform: translate(-10%, -110%) rotate(10deg);
}
 @keyframes anim_circle-npd {
     to {
         stroke-dashoffset: 132;
    }
}
 @keyframes anim_circle-business-con {
     to {
         stroke-dashoffset: 142;
    }
}
 @keyframes anim_circle-capex {
     to {
         stroke-dashoffset: 155;
    }
}
 @keyframes anim_circle-child-part-inv {
     to {
         stroke-dashoffset: 404.8;
    }
}
}
</style>


<div class="container">

    <div class="container__progressbars">

        <div class="progressbar">
            <svg class="progressbar__svg">
                <circle cx=" 100" cy="60" r="55" class="progressbar__svg-circle circle-npd shadow-npd"> </circle>
            </svg>
            <span class="progressbar__text shadow-npd">95%</span>
                <span class="progressbar__topic shadow-npd"><style></style> NPD Revenue</span>
        </div>

        <div class="progressbar">
            <svg class="progressbar__svg">
                <circle cx="100" cy="60" r="55" class="progressbar__svg-circle circle-business-con shadow-business-con"> </circle>
            </svg>
            <span class="progressbar__text shadow-business-con">85%</span>
            <span class="progressbar__topic shadow-business-con">Business Conversion</span>
        </div>

        <div class="progressbar">
            <svg class="progressbar__svg">
                <circle cx="100" cy="60" r="55" class="progressbar__svg-circle circle-capex shadow-capex"> </circle>
            </svg>
            <span class="progressbar__text shadow-capex">70%</span>
            <span class="progressbar__topic shadow-capex">................ Capex</span>
        </div>

        <div class="progressbar">
            <svg class="progressbar__svg">
                <circle cx="100" cy="60" r="55" class="progressbar__svg-circle circle-child-part-inv shadow-child-part-inv"> </circle>
            </svg>
            <span class="progressbar__text shadow-child-part-inv">8%</span>
            <span class="progressbar__topic shadow-child-part-inv"> Child Part Inventory</span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: These progress bars are actually just rounded dashed strokes that are stretched using `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset`. It will be quite hard to control the stroke start and end points to specify the bar look. I would recommend using some other approach to achieve a similar result. For example, the SVG path can do the same but will require to be generated using JS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small amount of math needed to calculate the `stroke-dashoffset` needed via JS, but once you have that function then add listeners to buttons that have the specific percentages you need and then update an `SVG` element accordingly. My example uses data attributes to save the percentages, but there are other ways to do so. Other styling is just for reference to keep the new elements visually separated from original HTML

```js
//Helper function to get circumference
const calculateCircumference = (radius) => {
  return (2 * Math.PI * radius).toFixed(2);
};

//Get stroke-dasharray total using circumference math
const circleEl = document.querySelector('.progressbar__svg-circle');
let r = circleEl.getAttribute('r')
let c = calculateCircumference(r)

// Listen for button click, get progress data attribute, calculate new dash-offset and set style for the dynamic <circle> element
let dynamicProgressCirc = document.querySelector('.dynamic-progressbar-circle')
let progressbarBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.progressbar-btn')
progressbarBtns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
    let btnProgress = btn.getAttribute('data-progress')
    let newProgress = (c - (c * (btnProgress/100)))
    dynamicProgressCirc.style.strokeDashoffset = newProgress
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
  width: 700px;
  height: 220;
}

.container__progressbars {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  min-width: 170px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.progressbar {
  position: relative;
  width: 170px;
  height: 270px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.progressbar__svg {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.progressbar__svg-circle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke-dasharray: 345.58;
  stroke-dashoffset: 345.58;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  transform: translate(3px, 3px);
}
.shadow-npd {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #f63);
}
.shadow-business-con {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #3bf);
}
.shadow-capex {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #f3f);
}
.shadow-child-part-inv {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #ff3);
}
.circle-npd {
  animation: anim_circle-npd 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}
.circle-business-con {
  animation: anim_circle-business-con 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}
.circle-capex {
  animation: anim_circle-capex 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}
.circle-child-part-inv {
  animation: anim_circle-child-part-inv 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}
.progressbar__text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  transform: translate(-10%, -110%) rotate(10deg);
}
@keyframes anim_circle-npd {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 17.279;
  }
}
@keyframes anim_circle-business-con {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 51.837
  }
}
@keyframes anim_circle-capex {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 103.674
  }
}
@keyframes anim_circle-child-part-inv {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 317.933
  }
}

/* Dynamic Progressbar CSS */
.dynamic-progressbar-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #EAEEF2;
}
.dynamic-progressbar-container .progressbar__svg-circle {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #000);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.buttons-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}
.progressbar-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 4rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}
.progressbar-btn:hover,
.progressbar-btn:focus,
.progressbar-btn:active {
  background: #194B74;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="dynamic-progressbar-container">
    <svg class="progressbar__svg">
      <circle cx="100" cy="60" r="55" class="progressbar__svg-circle dynamic-progressbar-circle"> </circle>
    </svg>
    <div class="buttons-container">
      <button class="progressbar-btn" data-progress="95">95%</button>
      <button class="progressbar-btn" data-progress="85">85%</button>
      <button class="progressbar-btn" data-progress="70">70%</button>
      <button class="progressbar-btn" data-progress="7">8%</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="container__progressbars">

      <div class="progressbar">
        <svg class="progressbar__svg">
          <circle cx=" 100" cy="60" r="55" class="progressbar__svg-circle circle-npd shadow-npd"> </circle>
        </svg>
        <span class="progressbar__text shadow-npd">95%</span>
        <span class="progressbar__topic shadow-npd"><style></style> NPD Revenue</span>
      </div>

      <div class="progressbar">
        <svg class="progressbar__svg">
          <circle cx="100" cy="60" r="55" class="progressbar__svg-circle circle-business-con shadow-business-con"> </circle>
        </svg>
        <span class="progressbar__text shadow-business-con">85%</span>
        <span class="progressbar__topic shadow-business-con">Business Conversion</span>
      </div>

      <div class="progressbar">
        <svg class="progressbar__svg">
          <circle cx="100" cy="60" r="55" class="progressbar__svg-circle circle-capex shadow-capex"> </circle>
        </svg>
        <span class="progressbar__text shadow-capex">70%</span>
        <span class="progressbar__topic shadow-capex">................ Capex</span>
      </div>

      <div class="progressbar">
        <svg class="progressbar__svg">
          <circle cx="100" cy="60" r="55" class="progressbar__svg-circle circle-child-part-inv shadow-child-part-inv"> </circle>
        </svg>
        <span class="progressbar__text shadow-child-part-inv">8%</span>
        <span class="progressbar__topic shadow-child-part-inv"> Child Part Inventory</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```